Considering enthalpy of formation and sensible enthalpy in steady-flow systems
I am reading a book (Thermodynamics an Engineering approach), I am reading over the section of steady-flow systems with chemical reactions.
The book just introduced the following formula for the enthalpy (per mole) of a component as:
$$\bar{H} = \bar{h_f^o} + (\bar{h} - \bar{h^o})$$
Where $\bar{h_f^o}$ is the standard enthalpy of formation at the reference state of 25 ºC and 1 atm, and $\bar{h^o}$ is the sensible enthalpy at the standard reference state of 25 ºC and 1 atm.
How are these two quantities different?
In my book they give an example where they calculate the enthalpy for oxygen at 7 ºC, they express it as:
$$\bar{H}_{O_2, @7 ºC} = (0 +\bar{h}_{280K} - \bar{h}_{298K} ) $$
where $\bar{h}_{280K} $ = 8150 kJ/kmol
and $\bar{h}_{298K} $ = 8669 kJ/mol
Considering the work done by a turbine as $W = \dot{m}(h_{10kPa}-h_{5kPa})$ I'd normally take the enthalpy values given by a pressure table and use that directly. I can see that using $\bar{H}$ the term, $\bar{h_f^o}$, will cancel out if there are no chemical changes in the system.
I do not quite get how this enthalpies values relate-to or differ from the ones that are listed in pressure or temperature tables.

Can you short out the chemistry equation arrow in: $\ce{1 kmol O_2 \cdot (0 +\bar{h}{280K} - \bar{h}{298K} ) }$ ?

In your first equation, the difference in parentheses is the sensible enthalpy change, that is due to temperature only (for ideal gas enthalpy is function of temperature only). The first $h_f$ with circle is the standard enthalpy of formation which is zero for an element in the most common state (so for O2 it
is zero). The values you quote use a different zero for enthalpy (probably 0 at 0 K).
Your comment on the turbine is mostly correct, if you get values from one table the differences of enthalpy are good. Dealing with steam you may need a table for enthalpy as function of temperature and pressure.

Thank you very much for your response, really appreciate it.
I was also wondering, if the listed $h$ values in the tables correspond to $h$ in $h_f + h - h_0$ or would they correspond to just $h$?

The author uses $h^o$ (the last h in equation)  for enthalpy at his reference point (25 C).  The first $h$ is for standard enthalpy of formation. For combustion of say methane with oxygen to yield carbon dioxide, the standard heat of formation of each allows you to calculate the heat release.
